# ActionListener for Button in different Class?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I've got a problem, I've got 5  Classes. 1 of them is the MainGUI, the other one is a JPanel with Buttons (but the buttons are not from the JPanels Class but from the 3rd, 4th and 5th class) and the 3 Button Classes.
I don't know if the structure is kinda dumb (correct me if I am wrong, it's just for experience).
So the biggest Problem here is that I can't use the ActionListeners for each Button. I'd like to change the text of a (J)Textfield from another class called JPanelTime.
The Code looks like this:

**MainGUI.java**

```
package view;
//Removed the javax.swing.*, etc imports because it's taking too much space

import listener.StartButton;

public class MainGUI{

private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stoppuhr");


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    MainGUI gui = new MainGUI();
    gui.run();
}

public void run() throws IOException{
    frame.setSize(400, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanelTime timePanel = new JPanelTime();
    frame.add(timePanel.getGUI(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JPanelButtons buttonPanel = new JPanelButtons();
    frame.add(buttonPanel.getGUI(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    JPanelPicture picturePanel = new JPanelPicture();
    frame.add(picturePanel.getGUI(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

**JPanelButtons.java**

```
package view;
//Same as above

import listener.MeantimeButton;
import listener.StartButton;
import listener.StopButton;

public class JPanelButtons extends JPanel{

private JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

public JPanelButtons(){
    StartButton startButton = new StartButton();
    StopButton stopButton = new StopButton();
    MeantimeButton meantimeButton = new MeantimeButton();

    buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Buttons"));
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));

    startButton.setText("Start");
    meantimeButton.setText("Zwischenzeit");
    stopButton.setText("Stopp");
    buttonPanel.add(startButton);
    buttonPanel.add(meantimeButton);
    buttonPanel.add(stopButton);
}


public JComponent getGUI(){
    return buttonPanel;
}
}
```

**StartButton.java**

```
package listener;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import view.MainGUI;

public class StartButton extends JButton implements ActionListener{


public StartButton() {
    JButton startButton = new JButton();
    startButton.addActionListener(this);
    startButton.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Date now = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat thisDate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    String getDate = thisDate.format(now);

    }

}
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Uhm, I still don't get your question. But if it's about setting a Listener for a Button you could give it a own method called `setActionListener(ActionListener al)` and call it from your other class where you created that object.

Comment: I don't think it's good practice to make a class for each button. You can simply add `protected static JButton startBtn = new JButton("Start");` to the ButtonsPanel.

And set the action listener for each one from MainGUI.

Comment: @MuratK. and Price (seems like I can only notify one, sadly) , seems like I may have found the solution by adding that code   `ActionListener act = new StartButton();
  startButton.addActionListener(act);`     I'll update the post as soon as I bring it to work. Thanks for your answer though!